# WIX Office installer not uninstalling Plugin

Tags: plugins, outlook, wix, ms-office

I have created a WIX Install MSI file for my Office Outlook Plugin. Everything runs fine however when i uninstall it through add/remove programs everything is removed except for the Plugin in Outlook. It runs but gives errors because the other components are now missing. How can I get it to remove it without going to Outlook and removing the plugin manually?

I have added the "RemoveFolder" tag in the XML which has no effect.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your actual XML code. Could you share it? And I suppose you made sure that Outlook wasn't running during uninstall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are doing some kind of active setup trick to do HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry propogation.  I'd suggest not doing this and instead register the extension in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.  This way when the uninstall runs it can access all of the components that need to be removed.   There are gotchas in terms of  different patch versions of different versions of office and how they behave in terms of supporting per-machine registration of AddIns.  Details can be found in blog articles that I've written over the years titled VSTO lessons learned.

Comment: Thanks, I was using HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE but moved it over to HKEY_CURRENT_USER which seems to be working 100%.